# How to hide dynamic properties in OData .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I have a class that have dynamic properties. In dynamic property I want to show interface property (because OData does not support interface EDM yet). For example:

```
 public class Student
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IBackpack Backpack
        {
            get
            {
                return new Backpack() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
            }
            set
            {

            }
        }

        Dictionary<string, object> interfaces;
        public Dictionary<string, object> Interfaces
        {
            get
            {
                if (interfaces == null)
                {
                    interfaces = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "Backpack", this.Backpack as Backpack }
                    };
                }
                return interfaces;
            }
            set
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

My model config is :

```
 static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(ODataConventionModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.EntityType<IEntity>().Abstract().HasKey(s => s.Id);
            var entity = builder.EntityType<Student>();
            entity.Ignore(s => s.Backpack);
            builder.EntityType<Backpack>();
            builder.EntitySet<Student>("Student");
            var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
            return model;
        }
```

When I send request: https://localhost:44383/odata/Student
I am getting:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44383/OData/$metadata#Student",
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": "18d63120-75e3-4039-ae41-23f2f5550cc7",
            "Name": "Test",
            "Backpack": {
                "@odata.type": "#ODataCoreTest.Backpack",
                "Id": "ac37d6ab-9064-4b54-ac33-84a4639e26c5"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't want to show dynamic properites when it was not selected. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi @DIIshod K,What is your version of odata and asp.net core?I could not reproduce your issue.More details would help us reproduce and resolve your issue quickly.

Comment: @Rena Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement custom `ODataResourceSerializer` and override `AppendDynamicProperties`

```
public class CustomODataResourceSerializer : ODataResourceSerializer
{
    public CustomODataResourceSerializer(ODataSerializerProvider serializerProvider) : base(serializerProvider)
    {

    }

    public override void AppendDynamicProperties(ODataResource resource, SelectExpandNode selectExpandNode, ResourceContext resourceContext)
    {
        if (selectExpandNode.SelectedDynamicProperties?.Any() == true)
        {
            base.AppendDynamicProperties(resource, selectExpandNode, resourceContext);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomODataSerializerProvider : DefaultODataSerializerProvider
{
    private CustomODataResourceSerializer resuoruceSerializer;


    public CustomODataSerializerProvider(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        resuoruceSerializer = new CustomODataResourceSerializer(this);
    }

    public override ODataEdmTypeSerializer GetEdmTypeSerializer(IEdmTypeReference edmType)
    {
        if (edmType.IsEntity())
        {
            return resuoruceSerializer;
        }
        return base.GetEdmTypeSerializer(edmType);
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
configureAction.AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, typeof(ODataSerializerProvider), sp => new CustomODataSerializerProvider(sp));
```